# Installing Antlrworks 2 plugin requires EditorSettingsStorage and EditorOptions

Tags: netbeans-7, antlrworks

I've been trying to install Antlrworks 2  into Netbeans, and the installer is demanding two other plugins. I have not been able to figure out where to find these, and my friend, using the same version of Netbeans, with most of the same plugins, on the same operating system, did not encounter this dialog. Any advice?

Comment: What version of Netbeans, which OS?

Comment: 7.3.1, on Mac OS X Lion 10.8.4